# Multiple regression p-value differs in summary and in pf() output used for extraction, in R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, p-value

When fitting multiple variables to one outcome via the `lm()` function in R, `summary(lm)` gives me the p-values for individual regressors but not for the full model in an easily extractable (as in, just accessing fields) kind of way.

According to [this question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-April/194123.html), it is possible to extract the p-value via `summary(lm)$fstatistic` by using the command:

```
pf(x$fstatistic[1],x$fstatistic[2],x$fstatistic[3],lower.tail=FALSE)
```

However, while in the example linked this provides the same p-value as is printed, I get a different one:

```
> summary(model)
# ...
Residual standard error: 1.533 on 371 degrees of freedom
  (555 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.3364,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2864 
F-statistic: 6.718 on 28 and 371 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

and:

```
f = summary(model)$fstatistic
> pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
       value 
5.948007e-20
```

What are possible reasons for these values to be different, and which one is the "right" one for the significance of the whole model?

Comment: I don't understand your problem: `5.948007e-20 < 2.2e-16`. `summary.lm` limits the precision of the printed p-value (which is appropriate).

Comment: First you say `R` does not give the p value for the full model from `summary(lm)` then you show an example where it does. Perhaps the issue is only *extracting* the p value.  Also, as @Roland implied, comparing p values with 16 or 20 initial 0's is fraught; but it is hard to conceive of a case where it matters whether the p value is one in a quadrillion or one in 10 quintillion (using American definitions of those terms).

Comment: Precision limiting for printing is fine, but even in that case `< 6e-20` would make more sense than `< 2.2e-16`. There is no reason to say "smaller than an arbitrary value", even if it is true. And yes, I meant extracting as you pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The p-value calculated by `print.summary.lm` (use `getAnywhere(print.summary.lm)` to study the code)  is rounded for floating point precision using `format.pval`.

`2.2e-16` is the value of `.Machine$double.eps`, which is

> the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1

So, the rounding is not arbitrary, but for numerical reasons.